# Fatal signal 11 after trying to open a canvas with a textEdit and custom font

Tags: android, canvas, fonts

I have an android app (created with android studio) that displays thing ina canvas. One possibility is to insert a EditText with a custom font. I'm able to save this, and open this activity once. But, when I try to open it a secon time, it crashes my app with the error:

```
 Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0xb844fc48 in tid 16935 (FinalizerDaemon)
```

I also have an ExceptionHandler, but it can't get this crash. I have red many other topics, but never found anything like my problem. The fonts are on the right place I think. Otherwise they wouldn't be opened the first time,

Regards.

Comment: TextEdit doesn't exist. It's called "EditText".

Comment: Right, sorry, EditText